# Why RPC(Remote Procedure Call) is picked rather that REST in Web3 field?

Tags: rest, ethereum, blockchain, rpc, web3js

I'm a frontend dev, currently working on web3 field.

As a frontend developer, highly familiar with REST communication,

I'm having interest why eventually RPC got picked rather that REST on crypto field.

what kind of points where better than REST?

I've googled about benefits of RPC , compairision between of them, but couldn't find edge benefits of using RPC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes also support WebSockets and even IPC transports, which are message-based communication, therefor RPC is better suited for HTTP requests, rather than REST.